# Does Windows 7 properly detect SSD when installing from scratch?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

When installing Windows 7 on a new SSD unit with just a single partition, should I care about:

- partition alignment?
- enabling SSD optimizations?
- disabling HDD stuff (defrag, superfetch, etc)?

Or will it detect and configure all automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nice article on Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5586733/how-to-take-full-advantage-of-your-solid+state-drive), explains everything, see section "Popular Tweaks That You Probably Don't Need"

[You also may want to apply this Windows patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982018) after windows is installed, not sure if automatic Windows Updates applies this one or not.

Answer (score 1):

Long answer: [Yes](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217070150/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx) ... Windows 7 will auto configure SSD drives.

Comment: Yes he should care, or yes it will configure all automatically?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, Windows 7 will auto configure SSD drives.

Comment: So please put that into your answer, to make it clear.  The OP did after all ask more than one question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a reliable answer since it is not based on formal research, but on my own experience.

I installed a brand new unformatted SSD after enabling AHCI in the BIOS, and removed the existing HDD. Put Windows 7 disc in the DVD drive and...

What W7 did:

- It properly created a new NTFS partition and also created a hidden system partition to ensure correct alignment.
- It enabled TRIM.

What W7 forgot about:

- It did not disable superfetch.
- It did not disable prefetcher.
- It did not disable defrag.

I also disabled indexing.